# Getting Button Text Vertically Centred on Android Emulator but not on IOS Emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, button, cross-platform

Same flutter code for outlined Button is giving text inside it as vertically centred when I run it on Android Emulator but when I run it on IOS Emulator text is lifted upward.

Here is the code for it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class WaterTemp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) *
        0.13,
    child: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (ctx, constraints) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.2,
              width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.6,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text('WATER TEMPERATURE'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.1,
            ),
            Container(
              height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.4,
              width: constraints.maxWidth * 1,
              child: 
                  OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                      minimumSize: Size(constraints.maxWidth * 0.48, 50),
                      maximumSize: Size(constraints.maxWidth * 0.48, 50),
                      textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Normal",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcRDH.png)
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontFamily: 'GothamMedium'
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    ));
}
}
```

This is a screen shot of android emulator : -

[image]

This is a screen shot of iphone : -

[image]

I have tried Align, centre and padding widgets as well as fitted box. Is there any other solution to it.

Comment: This is happening when using a specific font family. I changed the font family to get it right. but I want to know why this font acts like this.and how can it be solved.